# Change body of ServerWebExchange response in WebFilter

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-filter

I am trying to make an application in spring webflux. But there is a lot of stuff that I can't find in the documentation.
I have a webfilter where I want to add a wrapper around the response. Example:
Reponse before:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "asdf"
}
```

Response after:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "asdf"
    }
}
```

This is the WebFilter at the moment:

```
@Component
public class ResponseWrapperFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
        // Add wrapper to the response content...

        return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
    }
}
```

But I can't find a way to get or edit the body of the response.
How can I change the response output in a `WebFilter`?

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://medium.com/@jonathanrpx/a-json-response-filter-implementation-for-spring-webflux-ea82a6e21a99) can help.

Comment: response.writeWith(Mono.just(response.bufferFactory().wrap("response text".getBytes()))

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the javadoc, `WebFilter` is made for application-agnostic, cross-cutting concerns. `WebFilters` usually mutate the request headers, add attributes to the exchange or handle the response altogether without delegating to the rest of the chain.

I don't think that what you're trying to achieve is easily doable or even something that should be achieved this way. At the raw exchange level, you're dealing with a `Flux<DataBuffer>`, which is the response body split randomly in groups of bytes.

You could somehow wrap the response in a filter and use `Flux.concat` to prepend and append data to the actual response written by the handler. But there are a lot of questions regarding encoding, infinite streams, etc.

Maybe this is a concern that should be achieved at the `Encoder` level, since there you could restrict that behavior to a particular media type.